# Author URL using wrong domain after using Edit Author Slug

Tags: permalinks, author

I was trying Edit Author Slug Plugin and after base changes, I figured out that my Author Url is broken.

It was https://aditya-aman.com/author/aditya-aman/ but now its

https://aditya-aman.com/author/aditya-aman/

The domain name is AdityaAman.com? How the plugin changed the domain name?[image]

Answer (score 0):

I oubt the plugin will change your site URL. Can you please check your `wp_options` table and look for the `siteurl` and `home` options - please check these are both set to the correct URL.

Can you log-in to the admin area still? You may need to refresh your permalinks. If not, try to rename the plugin so that it gets disabled and see if you can access your site again.

If there is a problem with the plugin itself, you should ask for support via their forums / email as it's not on-topic for this site.